# The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup?

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to use the Dell OpenManage Ansible Modules to communicate with a PowerEdge's iDRAC. I cannot find a solution to my problem online, hopefully someone here will be able to assist. The only real answer I have found is that the host machine might not be using Python but as you can see from the error below, the host is in fact using a python interpreter. It is not the exact same interpreter as what is in the virtual environment I am running the playbook out of, I am not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Device:
PowerEdge R620 and iDRAC7

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: PowerEdge
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Get hardware inventory
    dellemc_get_system_inventory:
      idrac_ip:  "IP"
      idrac_user:  "USER"
      idrac_password:  "PASSWORD"
      validate_certs: false
    become: yes
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i iDRAC_IP, -u USER --ask-pass -vvv -K
```

Error:

```
fatal: [iDRAC_IP]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "Shared connection to iDRAC_IP closed.\r\n",
            "module_stdout": "\rcmdstat\r\n\r\tstatus       : 2\r\n\r\tstatus_tag   : COMMAND PROCESSING FAILED\r\n\r\terror        : 252\r\n\r\terror_tag    : COMMAND SYNTAX ERROR\r\n",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0,
            "warnings": [
                "Platform unknown on host iDRAC_IP is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.13/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information."
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the host machine might not be using Python but as you can see from the error below

This module uses a REST API which uses port 443.

Ansible doesn't like to use passwords, it is highly reccomended to use SSH Keys. Here is a tutorial to make the keys and place them on ESXI (stop at the ESXI part).

[Create SSH Keys](https://networklessons.com/uncategorized/vmware-esxi-ssh-public-key-authentication)

To place the SSH key on an iDRAC (I used this method on a Dell PowerEdge FC430), follow the directions on Page 77 of this reference guide.

[Placing SSH Keys on iDRAC](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/idrac7-8-with-lc-v2.20.20.20_reference-guide_en-us.pdf)

The playbook that worked for me

```
---
- hosts: host_file
  gather_facts: False
  collections: dellemc.openmanage
  tasks: 
    - name: Get System Inventory
      dellemc.openmanage.idrac_system_info: 
      idrac_ip: ip 
      idrac_password: pass
      idrac_user: user
      validate_certs: False
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Host file contains:

- host IP address
- ansible_connection=ssh
- remote username

Calling ansible playbook

> ansible-playbook -vvvv <your_file>.yml

If that doesn't work, you should verify that python is upgraded to [3.8.6](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/dellemc/openmanage/idrac_system_info_module.html#id2), and check if the iDRAC firmware upgraded to [2.82.82.82](https://github.com/dell/dellemc-openmanage-ansible-modules#supported-platforms).